# Access denied error for Attaching debugger to process - Intellij

Tags: go, intellij-idea, windows-services, remote-debugging

I try to attach Intellij debugger to running windwows service built in golang (running on the same machine). I am able to select the process from the list of available processes (Run -> Attach to process)

[image]

But it comes back with an error:

```
C:\Users\XPS\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\plugins\go\lib\dlv\windows\dlv.exe --listen=127.0.0.1:58872 --headless=true --api-version=2 --check-go-version=false --only-same-user=false attach 2336 --
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:58872
could not attach to pid 2336: Access is denied.

Debugger finished with the exit code 1
```

I checked that administrators have the "debug programs" rights assigned in Local security policy. Apart from that I don't know what the problem might be.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check if you have any antivirus running that may block it. Also, try using the `dlv` from the command line without Goland [1](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/usage/dlv_attach.md) [2](https://wiki.crdb.io/wiki/spaces/CRDB/pages/82411849/Debugging+with+Delve) can help you if this issue a IntelliJ issue or some permission/network/antivirus problem.